# How to traverse directory tree and continue loop?

Tags: python, loops, traversal

I'm trying to learn python. I'm trying to traverse a directory and print directory paths, digits extracted from directory names and file names, but my loop does not continue: it prints this info only from the first directory. How to continue this loop?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import re

#change directory
os.chdir('/Users/me/Pictures/')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for i in dirs: 
        val = re.search('\d+', i) 
        if val:
            a = os.path.join(root, i)
            for f in files:
                print a, val.group(0), f
```

Comment: perhaps the `if val` condition is only true once?

Comment: *“digits extracted from directory names and file names”* – Note that you only check *directory names* but not file names. And once you found a directory name with a number, you print out the files *of the root folder* for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are matching the names of *subdirectories*, not the name of the *current* directory. If you only have *one level* of nested directories with digits your `if` statement will be wrong as soon as you enter into those subdirectories.

I don't think you understand that in each iteration, `root` is the path to the *directory being listed*, and `dirs` is a list of names of **sub**directories.

Match against `root` instead:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    dirname = os.path.basename(root)
    val = re.search('\d+', dirname) 
    if val:
        for f in files:
            print a, val.group(0), f
```